# Getting results based on condition from another table in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, database

I have got two tables for a Microhydel Application, one consists the monthly billing record of Consumers from which monthly customer Bill is generated.

```
CREATE TABLE billing_history(
    [id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [reading_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [reading_year] [smallint] NULL,
    [reading] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [consumer_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [paid_amount] [numeric](18, 0) NULL)
```

I have another table which stores the different slab for per unit cost for both commercial and domestic users.

```
CREATE TABLE [rate_list](
    [flag] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [limit] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [price] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [service_charges] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [surcharge] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
)
```

For e.g For a Domestic customer consuming 50 units or less electricity monthly will be charged differently then a Commercial customer consuming the same amount of electricity. Similarly consuming units over this slab will have another rate applied on them.

Thanks to @bluefeet i already have the query to generate the numbers of units consumed from the first table using the query

```
select c.consumer_id, 
  sum(c.reading - isnull(pre.reading, 0)) TotalReading
from
(
  select consumer_id,
    reading,
    month(getdate()) curMonth,
    year(getdate()) curYear,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then 12 else month(getdate()) -1 end preMonth,
    case when month(getdate()) = 1 then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end preYear
  from billing_history
  where month(reading_date) = month(getdate())
    and year(reading_date) = year(getdate())
) c
left join billing_history pre
  on c.consumer_id = pre.consumer_id
  and month(pre.reading_date) = c.preMonth
  and year(pre.reading_date) = c.preYear
group by c.consumer_id;
```

However I need to generate Monthly bill for each customer so that for e.g according to the rates in the rate_list table. The Key here is DOMESTIC/COMMERCIAL which has different slabs for the number of units consumed.

Any ideas

Comment: If you can show your data or create two tables with some data on [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that would be helpful.

Comment: What column identifies either domestic or commercial? Can you post some sample data for the `rate_list` and the `billing_history` table?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/093bb

Comment: A customer main table consisting of the customer details has the field type_of_connection which can either be DOMESTIC OR COMMERCIAL.

Comment: @user2018756 Is the `limit` value in the `price_list` table the range values?  So it is `0-50` will have a price of 4 and `51-100` has `10`. If so, what is over 100?

Comment: Yes it is. There is a difference of rate on every 50 Units. So it is 0-50 and then 51-100 and 101-150 and so on, right uptil 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments on my answer.

First, I wasn't not sure where the `type_of_connection` flag is present in the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/093bb) that you posted so I added it to `Consumers`.

Second, I think you need to alter your `price_list2` table to include the `limit` start and end values for the prices. Otherwise it will be very difficult to determine the price for each consumer.

I used the following `price_list2` table which will contain the start/end values for each limit:

```
CREATE TABLE [price_list2](
    [flag] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [limitStart] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [limitEnd] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [price] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [service_charges] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [surcharge] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL);
```

On to the query, using the tables and the original query that you posted you should be able to use something like this:

```
select c.consumer_id,
  r.totalreading * p.price TotalBill
from Consumers c
inner join
(
  select c.consumer_id, 
    sum(c.reading - isnull(pre.reading, 0)) TotalReading
  from
  (
    select consumer_id,
      reading,
      month(getdate()) curMonth,
      year(getdate()) curYear,
      case when month(getdate()) = 1 then 12 else month(getdate()) -1 end preMonth,
      case when month(getdate()) = 1 then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end preYear
    from billing_history
    where month(reading_date) = month(getdate())
      and year(reading_date) = year(getdate())
  ) c
  left join billing_history pre
    on c.consumer_id = pre.consumer_id
    and month(pre.reading_date) = c.preMonth
    and year(pre.reading_date) = c.preYear
  group by c.consumer_id
) r
  on c.consumer_id = r.consumer_id
inner join price_list2 p
  on c.type_of_connection = p.flag
  and r.totalreading between p.limitStart and p.limitEnd
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/00b31/3)

As you can see when joining on the `price_list2` table I am joining on the start/end range of the limits.  This allows you to determine what price should be used for the bill.

Comment: Thanks yet again @bluefeet. It worked perfectly, though the application_type field in the customers table held the connection_type value. Only had to change that. Thanks a million.